# Gradient descent algorithm error non-comformable arguments

Tags: r, algorithm, gradient-descent

I am trying to perform a linear regression from scratch in R, without using any packages or libraries. The data I am using is:

> UCI Machine Learning Repository, Bike-Sharing-Dataset

I must apply a batch update gradient descent algorithm to this regression.

I have composed the following code:

```
> # Load the data
> data <- read.csv("Bike-Sharing-Dataset/hour.csv")
> 
> # Select the useable features
> data1 <- data[, c("season", "mnth", "hr", "holiday", "weekday", "workingday", "weathersit", "temp", "atemp", "hum", "windspeed", "cnt")]
> 
> # Examine the data structure
> str(data1)
'data.frame':   17379 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ season    : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ mnth      : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ hr        : int  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ holiday   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ weekday   : int  6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ workingday: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ weathersit: int  1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ temp      : num  0.24 0.22 0.22 0.24 0.24 0.24 0.22 0.2 0.24 0.32 ...
 $ atemp     : num  0.288 0.273 0.273 0.288 0.288 ...
 $ hum       : num  0.81 0.8 0.8 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.8 0.86 0.75 0.76 ...
 $ windspeed : num  0 0 0 0 0 0.0896 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ cnt       : int  16 40 32 13 1 1 2 3 8 14 ...
> 
> summary(data1)
     season           mnth              hr           holiday           weekday        workingday       weathersit   
 Min.   :1.000   Min.   : 1.000   Min.   : 0.00   Min.   :0.00000   Min.   :0.000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :1.000  
 1st Qu.:2.000   1st Qu.: 4.000   1st Qu.: 6.00   1st Qu.:0.00000   1st Qu.:1.000   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:1.000  
 Median :3.000   Median : 7.000   Median :12.00   Median :0.00000   Median :3.000   Median :1.0000   Median :1.000  
 Mean   :2.502   Mean   : 6.538   Mean   :11.55   Mean   :0.02877   Mean   :3.004   Mean   :0.6827   Mean   :1.425  
 3rd Qu.:3.000   3rd Qu.:10.000   3rd Qu.:18.00   3rd Qu.:0.00000   3rd Qu.:5.000   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:2.000  
 Max.   :4.000   Max.   :12.000   Max.   :23.00   Max.   :1.00000   Max.   :6.000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :4.000  
      temp           atemp             hum           windspeed           cnt       
 Min.   :0.020   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :  1.0  
 1st Qu.:0.340   1st Qu.:0.3333   1st Qu.:0.4800   1st Qu.:0.1045   1st Qu.: 40.0  
 Median :0.500   Median :0.4848   Median :0.6300   Median :0.1940   Median :142.0  
 Mean   :0.497   Mean   :0.4758   Mean   :0.6272   Mean   :0.1901   Mean   :189.5  
 3rd Qu.:0.660   3rd Qu.:0.6212   3rd Qu.:0.7800   3rd Qu.:0.2537   3rd Qu.:281.0  
 Max.   :1.000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :0.8507   Max.   :977.0  
> 
> x0 <- rep(1, nrow(data1)) # column of 1's
> x1 <- data1[, c("season", "mnth", "hr", "holiday", "weekday", "workingday", "weathersit", "temp", "atemp", "hum", "windspeed")]
> # create the x- matrix of explanatory variables
> x <- as.matrix(cbind(x0,x1))
> 
> # create the y-matrix of dependent variables
> 
> y <- as.matrix(data1$cnt)
> m <- nrow(y)
> 
> solve(t(x)%*%x)%*%t(x)%*%y 
                   [,1]
x0           29.1810525
season       18.9876496
mnth          0.1589082
hr            7.4613187
holiday     -20.5845740
weekday       1.7134883
workingday    3.6982194
weathersit   -1.3296468
temp         93.0022705
atemp       227.1855491
hum        -222.1211201
windspeed    28.4864449
> 
> # define the gradient function dJ/dtheata: 1/m * (h(x)-y))*x where h(x) = x*theta
> # in matrix form this is as follows:
> grad <- function(x, y, theta) {
+   gradient <- (1/m)* (t(x) %*% ((x %*% t(theta)) - y))
+   return(t(gradient))
+ }
> # define gradient descent update algorithm
> grad.descent <- function(x, maxit){
+   theta <- matrix(c(0, 0), nrow=1) # Initialize the parameters
+   
+   alpha = .05 # set learning rate
+   for (i in 1:maxit) {
+     theta <- theta - alpha  * grad(x, y, theta)   
+   }
+   return(theta)
+ }
```

When I try to call the function and print the results of the gradient descent- I get the following error:

```
> print(grad.descent(x,1000))
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in x %*% t(theta) : non-conformable arguments 

> beta <- grad.descent(x,1000)
Error in x %*% t(theta) : non-conformable arguments
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: You initialize `theta` as a vector of length 2. It would seem that that's the wrong dimension. You have twelve variables in the model!

Comment: @coffeinjunky so should the vector length be 12? ie- `theta <- matrix(c(0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), nrow=1)` OR `theta <- matrix(c(0, 0), nrow=12)` im new to this and not quite sure what to do :/

Comment: I tried the first method and it just returned 'NaN' for all columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
grad.descent <- function(x, maxit){
  theta <- matrix(rep(0, length=ncol(x)), nrow = 1) 
  alpha = .05 # set learning rate
  for (i in 1:maxit) {
    theta <- theta - alpha  * grad(x, y, theta)   
  }
  return(theta)
}

grad.descent(x,10)
               x0       season          mnth            hr
[1,] -14980121331 -39045685399 -103624114379 -217515123951
        holiday      weekday   workingday   weathersit        temp
[1,] -428141889 -45772773208 -10250464667 -21311163894 -7687568533
           atemp         hum   windspeed
[1,] -7340863806 -9108715961 -2927915227
```

The error `non-conformable arguments` almost always indicates that some dimensions of your matrices do not match. In this case, you initiated `theta` as a matrix with dimension (1,2), but you have twelve variables.

On a related note, your step size is rather large, which is why you may end up with weird results. To see this, let's use the following:

```
grad <- function(x, y, theta) { # note that for readability, I redefined theta as a column vector
  gradient <-  1/m* t(x) %*% (x %*% theta - y) 
  return(gradient)
}
grad.descent <- function(x, maxit, alpha){
  theta <- matrix(rep(0, length=ncol(x)), ncol = 1)
  for (i in 1:maxit) {
    theta <- theta - alpha  * grad(x, y, theta)   
  }
  return(theta)
}
```

Let's do it with your alpha of 0.05 and with 0.005:

```
data.frame(alpha_0.05 = grad.descent(x, maxit = 1000, alpha = 0.05),
           alpha_0.005 = grad.descent(x, maxit = 1000, alpha = 0.005))
           alpha_0.05 alpha_0.005
x0                NaN    6.253737
season            NaN   31.968743
mnth              NaN   -2.317199
hr                NaN    9.904181
holiday           NaN   -2.986200
weekday           NaN    2.982280
workingday        NaN    8.961909
weathersit        NaN  -26.145486
temp              NaN   46.509991
atemp             NaN   41.258458
hum               NaN  -29.508986
windspeed         NaN    7.632146
```

Comment: Thank you, this works- but one thing I am worried about is that the results of the gradient descent are radically different from the results of the regression, why is this? Also, I get a warning message `> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In (x %*% t(theta)) - y :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

Comment: Great! The warning messages are gone- however, my results are still radically different from the results of the regression. Can you explain why this is?

Comment: With `maxit = 100000` and `alpha = 0.005`, they get pretty close. To get a more robust version, you could implement a convergence criterion using the difference in costs between two updates.

Comment: how would I implement the convergence criterion? if you see my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46163492/linear-regression-gradient-descent-algorithms-in-r-produce-varying-results, the first algorithm I think has a convergence criterion but Im not sure how to implement the same idea in this algorithm