# Linear regression gradient descent algorithms in R produce varying results

Tags: r, algorithm, plot, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement a linear regression in R from scratch without using any packages or libraries using the following data:

> UCI Machine Learning Repository, Bike-Sharing-Dataset

The linear regression was easy enough, here is the code:

```
data <- read.csv("Bike-Sharing-Dataset/hour.csv")

# Select the useable features
data1 <- data[, c("season", "mnth", "hr", "holiday", "weekday", "workingday", "weathersit", "temp", "atemp", "hum", "windspeed", "cnt")]

# Split the data
trainingObs<-sample(nrow(data1),0.70*nrow(data1),replace=FALSE)

# Create the training dataset
trainingDS<-data1[trainingObs,]

# Create the test dataset
testDS<-data1[-trainingObs,]

x0 <- rep(1, nrow(trainingDS)) # column of 1's
x1 <- trainingDS[, c("season", "mnth", "hr", "holiday", "weekday", "workingday", "weathersit", "temp", "atemp", "hum", "windspeed")]

# create the x- matrix of explanatory variables
x <- as.matrix(cbind(x0,x1))

# create the y-matrix of dependent variables

y <- as.matrix(trainingDS$cnt)
m <- nrow(y)

solve(t(x)%*%x)%*%t(x)%*%y
```

The next step is to implement the batch update gradient descent and here is where I am running into problems. I dont know where the errors are coming from or how to fix them, but the code works. The problem is that the values being produced are radically different from the results of the regression and I am unsure of why.

The two versions of the batch update gradient descent that I have implemented are as follows (the results of both algorithms differ from one another and from the results of the regression):

```
# Gradient descent 1
gradientDesc <- function(x, y, learn_rate, conv_threshold, n, max_iter) {
  plot(x, y, col = "blue", pch = 20)
  m <- runif(1, 0, 1)
  c <- runif(1, 0, 1)
  yhat <- m * x + c
  MSE <- sum((y - yhat) ^ 2) / n
  converged = F
  iterations = 0
  while(converged == F) {
    ## Implement the gradient descent algorithm
    m_new <- m - learn_rate * ((1 / n) * (sum((yhat - y) * x)))
    c_new <- c - learn_rate * ((1 / n) * (sum(yhat - y)))
    m <- m_new
    c <- c_new
    yhat <- m * x + c
    MSE_new <- sum((y - yhat) ^ 2) / n
    if(MSE - MSE_new <= conv_threshold) {
      abline(c, m) 
      converged = T
      return(paste("Optimal intercept:", c, "Optimal slope:", m))
    }
    iterations = iterations + 1
    if(iterations > max_iter) { 
      abline(c, m) 
      converged = T
      return(paste("Optimal intercept:", c, "Optimal slope:", m))
    }
  }
  return(paste("MSE=", MSE))
}
```

AND:

```
grad <- function(x, y, theta) { # note that for readability, I redefined theta as a column vector
  gradient <-  1/m* t(x) %*% (x %*% theta - y) 
  return(gradient)
}
grad.descent <- function(x, maxit, alpha){
  theta <- matrix(rep(0, length=ncol(x)), ncol = 1)
  for (i in 1:maxit) {
    theta <- theta - alpha  * grad(x, y, theta)   
  }
  return(theta)
}
```

If someone could explain why these two functions are producing different results I would greatly appreciate it. I also want to make sure that I am in fact implementing the gradient descent correctly.

Lastly, how can I plot the results of the descent with varying learning rates and superimpose this data over the results of the regression itself?

**EDIT**
Here are the results of running the two algorithms with alpha = .005 and 10,000 iterations:

1)

```
> gradientDesc(trainingDS, y, 0.005, 0.001, 32, 10000)
TEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
[1] "Optimal intercept: 2183458.95872599 Optimal slope: 62417773.0184353"
```

2)

```
> print(grad.descent(x, 10000, .005))
                   [,1]
x0            8.3681113
season       19.8399837
mnth         -0.3515479
hr            8.0269388
holiday     -16.2429750
weekday       1.9615369
workingday    7.6063719
weathersit  -12.0611266
temp        157.5315413
atemp       138.8019732
hum        -162.7948299
windspeed    31.5442471
```

Comment: Could you show what you have done to see that the results are different?

Comment: @coffeinjunky I added the results of the two algorithms- the first doesnt make sense to me at all

Comment: I find it hard to believe that your `gradientDesc` function works at all. Could you please try executing it with a clean R session and only with the code that you have provided above?

Comment: @coffeinjunky I ran it again with a clean R session and it produced the same results that I have posted above. lol- why does it look bad and how can I fix it? (I am pretty sure it doesnt "work" even though it is running)

Comment: To start with, you are passing an entire `data.frame` to the function (multiple columns), yet your `return` statements indicate only one. Your products `m*x` don't make much sense to me if there are indeed multiple columns. Moreover, looking at your first code chunk, you add a vector of ones to the `x` matrix. What is this code for? Are you using it? If you do use it, then your constant `c` can be removed from the code entirely. Last but not least, what is the role of `n` here? Maybe it would help if you specified your inputs. Is it a `vector`, a `matrix`, a `data.frame`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give you an example of how to write functions like this in a slightly better way, consider the following:

```
gradientDesc <- function(x, y, learn_rate, conv_threshold, max_iter) {
  n <- nrow(x) 
  m <- runif(ncol(x), 0, 1) # m is a vector of dimension ncol(x), 1
  yhat <- x %*% m # since x already contains a constant, no need to add another one

  MSE <- sum((y - yhat) ^ 2) / n

  converged = F
  iterations = 0

  while(converged == F) {
    m <- m - learn_rate * ( 1/n * t(x) %*% (yhat - y))
    yhat <- x %*% m
    MSE_new <- sum((y - yhat) ^ 2) / n

    if( abs(MSE - MSE_new) <= conv_threshold) {
      converged = T
    }
    iterations = iterations + 1
    MSE <- MSE_new

    if(iterations >= max_iter) break
  }
  return(list(converged = converged, 
              num_iterations = iterations, 
              MSE = MSE_new, 
              coefs = m) )
}
```

For comparison:

```
ols <- solve(t(x)%*%x)%*%t(x)%*%y
```

Now,

```
out <- gradientDesc(x,y, 0.005, 1e-7, 200000)

data.frame(ols, out$coefs)
                    ols    out.coefs
x0           33.0663095   35.2995589
season       18.5603565   18.5779534
mnth         -0.1441603   -0.1458521
hr            7.4374031    7.4420685
holiday     -21.0608520  -21.3284449
weekday       1.5115838    1.4813259
workingday    5.9953383    5.9643950
weathersit   -0.2990723   -0.4073493
temp        100.0719903  147.1157262
atemp       226.9828394  174.0260534
hum        -225.7411524 -225.2686640
windspeed    12.3671942    9.5792498
```

Here, `x` refers to your `x` as defined in your first code chunk. Note the similarity between the coefficients. However, also note that

```
out$converged
[1] FALSE
```

so that you could increase the accuracy by increasing the number of iterations or by playing around with the step size. It might also help to scale your variables first.

Comment: This is because you are passing a `data.frame` to the function, and not a matrix.

Comment: The threshold is specified as `1e-7`.

Comment: I changed MSE and MSE_new to cost and new_cost in order to reflect the change I made `cost <- sum((y - yhat) ^ 2) / (2*n)` (same for new_cost) but now when I try to run the code I get the following error: `> data.frame(betas, out$coefs)
Error in out$coefs : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Comment: @zsad512 I don't know what changes you made, but that error message is quite clear: your changes led to `out` being an atomic vector, and for this kind of data structure there is no `$` operator.

Comment: How can I print the results of `MSE` and `MSE_new`?

Comment: @zsad512 Using my code, this would be `out$MSE` for the latest MSE. You can easily add more output to the `list` that is returned, if you like. For debugging, writing `print(MSE)` in the corresponding line might help.

Comment: Is there a reason for the line `MSE <- MSE_new` ? I would like to know both values so that I can "measure" the effectiveness of the gradient descent as opposed to the error of the standard function.

Comment: What do you mean with 'both values'? There will be as many MSE values as there are iterations, not just two. In each iteration, you want to check if it was an improvement compared to the previous iteration, not to the initial one. That's why you need that line.